# Combination of shortest path and minumum spanning tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path

I've tried to do get minimum spanning tree of a undirected weighted graph.However, I need to find the shortest path between one or more pair of nodes.After that, I have to find minimum spanning tree of a graph. I've already found the shortest path between necessary nodes but I don't know how to find minimum spanning tree including these shortest paths. Let me give an example.

```
 G
 |2 
 H      A
 |1     |6      
 F      ------B
 |1           | 7
 E -----D-----C
    2      8
```

There is also an edge between A and E with 2 weight but I couldn't show it.

Now, First of all I need to find shortest path between A and E(I have to do it because of my application) which is A-E-D-C and then, connect all graph with minimum spanning. Is there anyone to help me give some clue ? Sorry for bad English its not my native language

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4):

**Just an MST**

If you just want the MST, this just involves running [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) (see below) or [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm):

> 1. Initialize a tree with a single vertex, chosen arbitrarily from the graph.
> 2. Grow the tree by one edge: Of the edges that connect the tree to vertices not yet in the tree, find the minimum-weight edge, and transfer it to the tree.
> 3. Repeat step 2 (until all vertices are in the tree).

This does not involve getting the shortest paths between vertices. In fact, it won't necessarily include some shortest paths. Consider:

```
  A
1 |\
  B \
1 |  \ 2
  C   \
1 |    \
  D-----E
     1
```

The shortest path between A and E is 2 (just directly from A to E), but the MST (A-B-C-D-E) doesn't include that edge.

**'MST' including some shortest path**

If you want to find the MST including some shortest path, this is a most interesting problem.

This can be solved by running Kruskal's algorithm with a minor variation.

Derived from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm):

- Create a forest F (a set of trees), where each vertex in the graph is a separate tree, excluding the vertices from the shortest path.
- Add the shortest path as a single tree to the forest
- Create a set S containing all the edges in the graph excluding the edges from the shortest path
- While S is nonempty and F is not yet spanning

  - Remove an edge with minimum weight from S
  - If that edge connects two different trees, then add it to the forest, combining two trees into a single tree
  - Otherwise discard that edge